# how to access object in template in Backbone

Tags: templates, backbone.js, render

My backbone code is :

```
var UserList=Backbone.View.extend({
            el:'.page',
            render:function() {
                var that=this;
                var users=new Users();
                users.fetch({
                    success:function(users){
                        var template=_.template($('#user-list-template').html(),{users:users.models});

                        that.$el.html(template);
                    }
                })

            }
        });
```

Template code :

```
<script type="text/template" id="user-list-template">
        <table class="table striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% _.each(users, function(user) { %>
                    <tr>
                    <td><%= user.get('firstname') %></td>
                    <td><%= user.get('lastname') %></td>
                    <td><%= user.get('age') %></td>
                </tr>
                <% }); %>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </script>
```

The code is throwing UncaughtReferenceError:users not defined . Please let me know how to correct the above code.

Comment: @nikhoshr : I have checked that example as well. But Im still not able to solve the issue. Can you let me know what is the issue with above?

Comment: Exactly what @mu explains in the linked duplicate : check http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/qg1txf67/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/qg1txf67/1/